# RSA Signature - Multiple Use Weakness

Tags: encryption, rsa, signature

I cite from [Fundamentals of Computer Security](http://www.springer.com/computer/security+and+cryptology/book/978-3-540-43101-5) (Chapter 7 on Digital Signature, Paragraph 7.3 on RSA Signatures, page 289):

> Multiple uses of the RSA Signature scheme tend to weaken it. The way out is to make subsequent signatures dependent on those previously generated.

- Why is this?
- Does it affect also the RSA Encryption scheme, or is it a weakness that comes from the knowledge of the message (and therefore affects only Signature schemes)?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say from that out-of-context statement.  It may be that they were talking about signatures with obsolete padding schemes (such as ISO 9796-1), or possibly just raw RSA (zero padding, which is even worse); it is possible with these padding, if you observe enough signatures, you could come up with a forgery.

On the other hand, there is no known weakness if you generate RSA signatures using a modern padding scheme, either PKCS #1.5 (which, I suppose, is a bit hard to call modern) or PSS.

Comment: Yeah, it was a kick in my eyes when I read that statement with no context!That's why I posted here, I just hadn't got any idea of what to search for...thks anyway, and I hope someone knows what's the point in it...

Comment: @Matteo: in addition, there's the suggestion "the way out is to make subsequent signatures dependent on those previously generated"; I cannot come up with any context where that makes sense.  If they drop in statements like that without saying what they mean, well, I would start questioning the expertise of the authors.

Comment: The subsequent suggestion is followed by the description of an algorithm proposed by [Cramer and Damgard](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.23.1069). However they discuss the algorithm without explaining why multiple use causes the scheme to be weakened.